# is ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED's behavior defined anywhere?

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

does anyone know what *exactly* ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED does? the api documentation for that constant is essentially blank.

it sounds like what i want (sync the supplied account first, before the others), but it's always good to know for sure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a definition in [Google's guide to Running a Sync Adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html#RunOnDemand). It's as follows:

> **SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED**
>
> Forces the sync to start immediately. If you
> don't set this, the system may wait several seconds before running the
> sync request, because it tries to optimize battery use by scheduling
> many requests in a short period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Google same word sends me here. See this answer [Starting just my sync immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6548585/1833505).

Yes, if you want to sync your app immediately(refresh your list):

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
extras.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
ContentResolver.requestSync(mAccount,ExampleContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY,extras);
```